# Method in Beans not working when called on xhtml

Tags: java, jsf

I have this cdBean.java with method called ViewAllCd to display all Cd in database. However, when it was called on xhtml, the output is not there.. How do I get the output?

This is my cdBean:

```
package Bean;

import Entities.Compactdiscs;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Named;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
 @Named
 @Stateless
public class cdBean implements cdBeanLocal {


@PersistenceUnit EntityManagerFactory emf;
/**
 *
 * @return
 */
@Override
public List<Compactdiscs> ViewAllCd(){
    return emf.createEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Compactdiscs.findAll",Compactdiscs.class).getResultList();
}

// Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
// "Insert Code > Add Business Method")
 }
```

And this is my xhtml file:

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
        >
      <head>
          <title>allcd</title>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      </head>
      <body>
         <h1>All Cd</h1>
                    <h:dataTable value="#{cdBean.ViewAllCd}" var="c" border="1">
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="ID" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{c.cdID}" />
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Name" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{c.cdName}" />
                        </h:column>

                    </h:dataTable>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: please use `h:head` instead of `head`, and `h:body` instead of `body` on your xhtml.

Comment: You are trying to merge the application layer and the domain model and/or business layer together. Please consider isolating them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this method. Richfaces expects getters and setters following (I don't remember the exact name) java naming conventions

`public List<Compactdiscs> getViewAllCd(){
    return your_data_here;
}`

Or you can do that to call your method:

```
 <h:dataTable value="#{cdBean.ViewAllCd()}" var="c" border="1">
```

Comment: Yes I've do that and still nothing when I run the project .. I don't know what is missing here..